# I cant install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8, uefi

I have a computer running windows 8.1, and I want to install ubuntu along side of it. However, my computer has some corrupted system files on it when I bought it, so I took it into a local store to have them look at it. They re-installed windows 8.1. Its all been working fine, until I went to install Ubuntu. I cannot access my UEFI firmware settings menu to turn off secure boot. So i tried changing my boot mode, through BIOS, to UEFI from Legacy. This worked! Ubuntu booted up and I started the install process but when I got to the part where I tell it what partition on my hard drive to put it on, it shows one partition of my whole hard drive with the full terabyte available for storage. And that's not the case, there should be 3. My windows system reserved partition, my main windows partition, and the 85 gigabyte partition I made for Ubuntu.

I change my boot mode to UEFI and turn off secure boot, install Ubuntu, and then go back and install windows. This makes me uneasy though as I'm not sure everything would work.

The main issue that I've figured out, cause I posted over at reddit too, is that the partitions cant be seen by the installer and I don't want to only run Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Go to disk management in windows and check for that extra storage place and if not of use then format it. After that you can proceed to installation.

If the problem persists please provide better insight to problem by errors prompted snaps, snapshot of the disk management from windows and fdisk command from live CD ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting into your live CD and selecting "try" instead of install. Then open a program called gparted (Click "Ubuntu button" and type in gparted). You should be able to see all the partitions currently on your hard drive.

Within the installer, at one point on the screen where it asks if you want to install Ubuntu in addition to or over your old operation system. On that same screen you should be able to click "advanced options" which will show you all the partitions currently on your HD and allow you to make new ones. In order to install Ubuntu you actually need two new partitions, the main partition which should be ext4 of whatever size you want and the swap partition which is just called swap and should generally be the same size as the amount of RAM in your computer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Wubi Method Of Installation for installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 8/8.1. In this method:

1. Open the downloaded ISO file.
2. Run Wubi.exe.
3. Select the relevant options on the Ubuntu Installer Window that open.
4. Select "Reboot Now" and Click Finish.

For more details visit this [link](http://www.99computertips.com/2015/03/install-ubuntu-directly-from-windows-on.html).

Comment: Wubi does bot support Windows 8.